# How to post images stored in a blob in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "Images" with id(int) and image(BLOB) where id is primary key.
I want to post the images stored in BLOB format along with its metadata to some other website. How can I do it ? Is there any way to do it.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Don't store images in blobs. DATAbase is for data, files belong to FILEsystem!

Comment: Who's to say a filesystem can't be a database (and vise versa)?

Answer (score 1):

Create the HTML site as usual. Make a normal `<img>` tag and set the src to a PHP file with some way of identifying the picture in the database, like the primary key field. The content of the PHP file could be something like this:

```
<?php
    $pkey = $_GET['pkey'];

    /* Code to fetch the image row from the database using the primary key */

    $image = $row['image']; 
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    print $image;
?>
```

That PHP file will now act as if you were requesting the image from a regular static file server.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways...

Depending on the size of the image data, you could use the data URI scheme in an HTML img tag to insert the image in to the web page.  See [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for more info on how to format the data.

Alternatively, (and more compatible), would be to create a page that will fetch the image data from your database and send back the proper content type header to make a browser think it's getting an image.  You would want to read up on HTTP Content-type headers and specifically how to send them to a browser via a scripting language on your server, etc...